# Styling table according to its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table: http://jsfiddle.net/UfhVc/1/

I am trying to:

1. Get the same style on all rows who have the same ID
2. Highlight the differences in each  on the rows with the same ID.

But right now I can't seem to figure out the logic needed for step 1). It's ok to use jQuery, I just found it easier to use plain js.

Also, I get a warning in this part of the code:

```
table.rows[i+1].cells[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var newColor = "#F1D0F2";
var diffColor = "#CECECE";

$('#tbl tr:gt(0)').each(function () { //Loop through the trs leaving out the header

    var txt = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(); //get the text of the id column
    var $this = $(this);

    var matchingRows = $('#tbl tr').not(this).filter(function () { //get the matching rows whose id colum value is same
        return $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() == txt; 
    }).css('background-color', newColor); //apply css for match

    matchingRows.find('td').css('background-color', function (i) { //apply background color
        if ($this.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').text() != this.innerHTML) return diffColor; // to the tds of matching rows but column valud differ.
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAcd3/)**

References:

- **[:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)**
- **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**
- **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**
- **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

**Edit**

Based on your comment here is the update:

```
var allColors = ["#333333","#990099", "#1295A6", "#FFFF99"]; //Set up the colors in to an array
var diffColor = "#CECECE";

$('#tbl tr:gt(0)').each(function () {

    var txt = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var $this = $(this);

     if($this.is('.transformed')) //check for class transformed is present if so this has already been processed skip it.
        return;

    //Get the matching rows whose id column value is same     
    var matchingRows = $('#tbl tr').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() == txt;
    }).css('background-color', allColors.shift()).addClass('transformed'); //Set the color and add a class to avoid latter processing

    matchingRows.find('td').css('background-color', function (i) { //apply background color
        var $parTd = $this.find('td:eq(' +  $(this).index() + ')');
        if ($.trim($parTd.text()) != $.trim(this.innerHTML)) // to the tds of matching rows but column value differ.
        {
            $parTd.css('background-color', diffColor);
            return diffColor;
        }
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kXrz/)**

Comment: I changed the table a bit in your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PAcd3/3/

Shouldn't that code make the ROW ids 3145 and 1042 from different background? I probably didn't explain well, but the rows with the same id have the same background but at the same time different background from other group of rows which share the same id with each other from the group.

Comment: @Cornwell ok you did not mention that in your question. Are u looking to have something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jDc8F/

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not being clear. That is exactly what I wanted to do. Just a question: if i add more rows it should work, right?
Because here they show up without background: http://jsfiddle.net/jDc8F/1/

Comment: Is it possible that instead of removing the colors from the array, i could loop through it somehow, so that if I had a table with 50 rows, the same color would repeat every X rows depending on the amount of colors in the array?

Comment: @Cornwell You could achieve with array itself. just use shift to remove the top and push the value to the end so that cycle repeats. Use this to test, i haven't tested. http://jsfiddle.net/VCnxM/. Also please do remember to mark as answer if your original question is answered at the least. :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I don't think I would get it working without you, or at least anytime soon.
Thanks again

Comment: @Cornwell You are welcome. i hope the latest answered you issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

For step one:

There are a few ways you can do it, I would probably attach a class to all table cells which are of a certain type, so you can easily select them all at once for editing.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you could simply query it with CSS like:

```
.id-cell {
  background-color:red;
}
```

But you can also just use more jQuery / JavaScript to find those table cells you're looking for anyways.  This fiddle uses jQuery to find all the cells which are in the "id" column, and paint the background red.

http://jsfiddle.net/8QL22/

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
$("table tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child").each(function(index) {
   var thisId = $(this);
   $("table tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child").each(function(_index) {
       if (index != _index && thisId.text() == $(this).text())
       {
           thisId.parent("tr").css("backgroundColor", "red");
           $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
           $(this).siblings("td").each(function(sindex) {
               var other = $(thisId.siblings()[sindex]);
               if (other.text() != $(this).text())
                   other.css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
           });
       }
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4mvp/